# Devexpress Gridview Filter Control

Tags: filter, devexpress, controls, aspxgridview

I have a ASPxGridView component that is filled from a SQL query
I wanted to apply a filter on my ASPX Gridview
so I wrote:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ID="gvExecReq" Visible="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        OnPageIndexChanged="gvExecReq_PageIndexChanged" OnBeforeColumnSortingGrouping="gvExecReq_BeforeColumnSortingGrouping">
        **<Settings ShowFilterRow="True" />
        <Settings ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowHeaderFilterButton="True" />**
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

the filter is well established, but it is not functional
What do I need to add more?

Comment: What do you mean by "not functional". It's not visible, it's visible it doesn't do anything, or it's visible but it works incorrectly? What kind of filter you need, filter row, header filter or filter control? You enabled all of them, all of them are non functional?

Comment: hello, I'm talking about the FilterBar which is visible but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Following Settings For Filter To Be Operational :

```
     <Settings ShowHeaderFilterButton="true"
     EnableFilterControlPopupMenuScrolling="True"
     ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" ShowFilterRowMenu="True" />
```

Also In The Columns of The Grid You Can Control The Condition of Filtering i.e. Contains, Equal, Does Not Contain etc.

```
  <dx:GridViewDataColumn  Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains" Settings-FilterMode="DisplayText">
```

Answer (score 0):

if in the database filed type is `string` you can write part of text for search,but is type of `int` or `decimal` or so on,you should write ALL text even it can find rows